# strings after "<" cannot be seen when using PHP strip_tags function

Tags: php, strip-tags

Let assume that $reply = "blah blah blah >*< blah blah blah";
(>*< is popular emoticon in korea)

but, when i use "strip_tags" to strip every html and php tags in $reply, every characters after "<" is removed.

i think strip_tags mixed up.

is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: no, unless you discard use of strip_tags

Comment: oh i see.. then i should use str_replacce instead of strip_tags. thanks!

Comment: @MintakSon: Most probably, you should use `htmlspecialchars`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're treating the string as HTML if you are calling `strip_tags()` on it. Therefore, those entities should be encoded as `&lt;` and `&gt;` before you use `strip_tags()` on it, otherwise they are to be treated as the start and end of HTML tags.

You will need to encode those entities. Using `strip_tags()` should then be *safe*.

Comment: +1, but what would be left for `strip_tags` to do after it's been processed with `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: oh! that's very good function! thank you for your advise. have a nice day, alex :)

Comment: i think using reg_expr -> htmlspecialchars -> strip_tags is the best way to solve the problem

Comment: When did regex's come into play ;).  And Jon had a good point here that using both strip_tags and htmlspecialchars() would be redundant.  Overkill, but it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting.  I would personally entity-encode the parts that are acceptable, then run strip tags or htmlentities() after that...

```
<?php
// Initial user-input
$reply = "blah blah blah >< blah blah blah";

// Allow the emoticon you mentioned
$reply = str_replace('><', '&gt;&lt;', $reply);

// Then strip tags
$reply = strip_tags($reply);
```

Of course, this is all moot if you just htmlentites($reply), and let the user put in brackets if they want...

Comment: `s/htmlentities/htmlspecialchars/` - in the days of UTF8 there's no good reason to encode things like umlauts as html entities.

Comment: Good point.  I always use htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), but mostly because that's what I saw other people do for i18n.  Is it better just to use htmlspecialchars()?

Comment: @landons: If your whole stack can handle UTF-8 (and as ThiefMaster says, this is almost 2012) then `htmlentities` is just more bloat. Plus, it makes the HTML unreadable.

Comment: @landons: `htmlspecialchars()` only encodes the characters which really *need* to be to prevent them having special meaning.

Comment: @landons What about some HTML such as `<strong><em>Whoops!</em></strong>`?

Comment: Interesting.  I had problems localizing an app a while back because of this.  All user input needed to be utf-8 encoded before database insertion.  Does this mean I messed up with the MySQL collation, or is there a better way to encode user-submitted data (And if you have to escape the special characters anyway...)?

Comment: @alex That's how it would appear on the page.  Far more people will be using brackets for emoticon/formatting reasons than will be doing so for script injection.  It makes sense to display what the user typed, so htmlentites('<strong><em>Whoops!</em></strong>') would translate to "&lt;strong&gt;..." and would display intuitively to normal users.  You're not as much "stripping html tags" as you are "filtering characters that should be encoded."